# Inserting data using dynamic textbox

Tags: jquery, html, phpmyadmin

i got a problem inserting data into mysql.

Error Message: Notice: Undefined index: total0, here's the php code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $NumQuery = $_POST['transaction'];
   $itemTotz = "";
   for ($xquery = 0; $xquery < $NumQuery; $xquery++) {

   $valpo_number = $_POST['inpo_number'];
   $valpo_date = $_POST['inpo_date'];                   
   $valitem = $xquery+1;
   $valquantity = $_POST['quantity'.$xquery.''];
   $valunit_price = $_POST['unitprice'.$xquery.''];
   $valtotal = $_POST['total'.$xquery.''];
   $valaprove_by = $_POST['inaprove_by'];
   $valprepared_by = $_POST['inprepared_by'];
   $valgrandtotal = $_POST['GrandTotal'];    

      if ($xquery == 0){
      $itemTotz .= $valitem;
      $valquantityTotz = $valquantity;
      $valunit_priceTotz = $valunit_price;
      $valtotalTotz = $valtotal;}
      else {
      $itemTotz .= "|".$valitem;
      $valquantityTotz .= "|".$valquantity;
      $valunit_priceTotz .= "|".$valunit_price;
      $valtotalTotz .= "|".$valtotal;}}
```

$query="INSERT INTO `purchasing_details`(`po_number`, `po_date`, `item`, `quantity`, `unit_price`, `total`, `aprove_by`, `prepared_by`, `GrandTotal`) VALUES ('$valpo_number','$valpo_date','$itemTotz','$valquantityTotz','$valunit_priceTotz','$valtotalTotz','$valaprove_by','$valprepared_by','$valgrandtotal')";
mysql_query($query) ;

```
       echo "<script language=javascript>
       alert('Purchasing Information Submitted!');
       </script>"; }
```

here's the javascript and variables, and computations

```
        function calculate(i) {
        var myunitprice = document.getElementById('unitprice' + i).value;
        var myquantity = document.getElementById('quantity' + i).value;
        var result = document.getElementById('total' + i);
        var myResult = myunitprice * myquantity;
        result.value = myResult.toFixed(2);
        TotalValue();}

        function TotalValue() {
        var totalValue = 0;
        $(document).find('input[name=total]').each(function(index, Obj) {
        if (isNaN(parseFloat($(Obj).val()))) $(Obj).val(0)
        totalValue += parseFloat($(Obj).val())})
        $('#GrandTotal').val(totalValue.toFixed(2))}

var php = '';
$('#transaction').on('change', function () {
    transaction = $(this).val();
    html = '<table>';
    for (var i = 0; i < transaction; i++) {
        html += '<tr><td><label>Quantity</label><input type="text" name="quantity' + i + '" id="quantity' + i + '" oninput="calculate(' + i + ')" /></td><td><label>Unit Price</label><input type="text" id="unitprice' + i + '" name="unitprice' + i + '" oninput="calculate(' + i + ')" />' +
            '</td><td><label>Total</label><input type="text" name="total" id="total' + i + '" /></td></tr>';
    }
    html += '</table><label>Grand Total </label><input type="text" id="GrandTotal" name="GrandTotal"/>'
$('#kidsFields').html(html);
$('.ui-page').trigger('create');
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The notice says you didn't post the `total0` field in your request at all.

Best thing here is to check your JavaScript and possible [Developer Tools (Network Tab)](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network) in Chrome or via [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) in Firefox to see what exactly you're sending to the server.